# Pass variable from C file to makefile

Tags: c, makefile

In my makefile, I added parameters to linker flags as a variable `BOOTLOAD`

```
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--section-start=.bootloader=$(BOOTLOAD)
```

If i write `BOOTLOAD = 0x3800` in makefile everything is working fine.

But i want to pass this variable from C code, so i tried to define it like `#define BOOTLOAD 0x3800`. But the linker cannot find it.

How should i pass `BOOTLOAD` from C file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of "passing" the macro from a C source file (which is possible but not easy), you could instead ask the preprocessor to define the macro when compiling with the `-D` option:

```
gcc -DBOOTLOAD=$(BOOTLOAD) -c source_file.c
```

I recommend you check the [GCC preprocessor command line option reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) for more information about the `-D` option.

---

It *is* possible to search a specific source file to the macro definition and then set a makefile variable to the extracted value, but it's easier to do it the other way around as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to grep BOOTLOAD from the source code in your makefile as follows:

```
BOOTLOAD = $(shell grep '#\s*define\s\+BOOTLOAD' YOUR_SOURCE_FILE | awk 'print $3')
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--section-start=.bootloader=$(BOOTLOAD)
```